# deserialize json

Tags: c#, json

I get this JSON resposne from a server:

```
{"User1":0, "User2":0,"User3":0,"User4":0,"User5":0,"UserN":0,}
```

Users can be from 0 to N.

I want to deserialize this JSON string into a List of Users

```
public class User
{
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public string Status{get;set;}
}
```

I try this but it doesn't work.

```
List<Users> peoples;

peoples = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Users>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the status property on the class to an int?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is not working is because the JSON string you are receiving is not a list of objects but a single object with multiple properties. A list is usually represented with `[]` in JSON:

```
[{"Name":"User0","Status":"0"},{"Name":"User1","Status":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
JavaScriptSerializer mySerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver());
```

Kind Regards,

Edit:

In your case:

```
peoples = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver()).Deserialize<List<Users>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Hi Trefex, i try your advance, but it doesn't  work.
It finish with this error

Cannot convert object of type 'System.Boolean' to : type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: Use this syntax also to serialize the object.