# Deserialize JSON that is a Single Object but needs to be List of Objects

Tags: json, vb.net

I apologize ahead of time because I don't even know how to ask this question. I am using FormStack and VB to get a list of Health Care Providers; up to 20. The way FormStack is returning this is as one object where each field is uniquely identified. Right now I have a class setup like so:

```
<JsonProperty("51791254")>
Property facility_name_01 As String
<JsonProperty("51791260")>
Property doctor_first_name_01 As String
<JsonProperty("51791294")>
Property doctor_last_name_01 As String
<JsonProperty("51791347")>
Property facility_address_1_01 As String
...
<JsonProperty("51792559")>
Property add_another_health_care_provider_01 As String

<JsonProperty("51792598")>
Property facility_name_02 As String
<JsonProperty("51792599")>
Property doctor_first_name_02 As String
<JsonProperty("51792600")>
Property doctor_last_name_02 As String
<JsonProperty("51792601")>
Property facility_address_1_02 As String
...
<JsonProperty("51792613")>
Property add_another_health_care_provider_02 As String
```

This list repeats to ..._20 for each health care provider. What I would like is to be able to loop through the json and create a list of up to 20 Health Care Providers if data exists. I guess my question; is there a more direct/better approach instead of creating a class with 344 properties that I then loop through and create a list of 20 HealthCareProividers with 17 properties, (the 4 extra fields are id fields). Again, I apologize about my ignorance in this area and appreciate any help and clarification.

I have been thrown in to the deep end and there is no life guard. More accurately, I am the life guard and haven't learned how to swim yet.

Sorry I did not include the JSON and thank you for the responses thus far

```
{"51791254":"HIllcrest Hoispital","51791260":"","51791294":"","51791347":"1234 Mayfield Rd","51791352":"","51791356":"Mayfield","51791361":"Ohio","51791384":"44124","51791388":"","51791397":"","51791399":"12/19/1974","51791415":"04/17/2017","51791510":"Treating","51791582":"106 | General Medicine","51791589":"Test entry for test client","51792559":"Yes","51792598":"Lake West","51792599":"","51792600":"","51792601":"1234 Euclid Ave","51792602":"","51792603":"Willoughby","51792604":"Ohio","51792605":"44092","51792606":"","51792607":"","51792608":"10/13/2003","51792609":"04/17/2017","51792610":"Diagnosing","51792611":"106 | General Medicine","51792612":"Second Test ","51792613":"Yes","51792970":"Rite Aid","51792971":"","51792972":"","51792973":"1234 SOM Center Rd","51792974":"","51792975":"Willoughby","51792976":"Ohio","51792977":"44092","51792978":"","51792979":"","51792980":"12/17/2013","51792981":"04/17/2017","51792982":"Pharmacy","51792983":"1 | Not Specified","51792984":"Test Pharmacy","51793056":"","51793057":"","51792876":"","51792877":"","51793033":"","51793034":"","51793015":"","51793016":"","51792997":"","51792998":"","51792963":"","51792964":"","51792945":"","51792946":"","51792928":"","51792929":"","51792911":"","51792912":"","51792893":"","51792894":"","51792753":"","51792754":"","51792859":"","51792860":"","51792842":"","51792843":"","51792825":"","51792826":"","51792808":"","51792809":"","51792791":"","51792792":"","51792774":"","51792775":"","51793552":"CFC3238D6271E613","51793634":"04/17/2017","51793722":"12:00:56"}
```

Thanks

BTW I looked at these two posts but don't understand them enough to implement.
Seems like what I am asking: 
 [deserialize json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196217/deserialize-json)
Not sure if this is even in the ball park:
[Linq to XML query works when returning single entity but needs to be of list<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619638/linq-to-xml-query-works-when-returning-single-entity-but-needs-to-be-of-listt)

Comment: Hmm.  Without seeing the actual json, I might deserialize to a dictionary where the keys are the `51791254` values, then use another dictionary or lookup to extract the data to individual objects stored to a collection.  The same could be done from a custom JSON.NET deserializer as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a sample of the JSON you wish to deserialize -- i.e. expand your question to a [mcve].

Comment: Can you include some of the JSON in the question as well?

Comment: Also, it might be easier to take the json string and split it up, and parse out the values from occurrences of `add_another_health_care_provider`. A class with 340 properties smells bad